# trec_eval's makefile generates errors on windows

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

Good morning,
I've got the same problem, here are the syntax errors mentionned bye the cygwin64 on windows7 :

```
$ make
gcc -g -I.  -Wall -DVERSIONID=\"9.0\"  -o trec_eval trec_eval.c ... m_Rprec_mult_avgjg.c m_P_avgjg.c -lm
    In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
                     from m_ndcg.c:9:
    m_ndcg.c:13:8: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
     double log2(double x);
            ^
    In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
                     from m_ndcg_cut.c:8:
    m_ndcg_cut.c:12:8: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
     double log2(double x);
            ^
    In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
                     from m_Rndcg.c:9:
    m_Rndcg.c:13:8: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
     double log2(double x);
            ^
    In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
                     from m_ndcg_rel.c:9:
    m_ndcg_rel.c:13:8: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
     double log2(double x);
            ^
    In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
                     from m_binG.c:9:
    m_binG.c:13:8: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
     double log2(double x);
            ^
    In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
                     from m_G.c:9:
    m_G.c:13:8: erreur : expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
     double log2(double x);
            ^
    make: *** [Makefile:54: trec_eval] Error 1
```

Is there someone that can help ?
Thanks

Comment: Please if there is someone experimented on trec_eval I need a help, thanks agan :)

Comment: you need to look on m_ndcg.c source code on lines before 12 and 13 for hints.

Comment: But worked on linux :(

Comment: cygwin is not linux, consider it a vanilla Unix. You need to debug the matter or provide more data to us. We can not guess your file content.

Comment: okay, I'll do it, thanks for you.